# Relation between dendroidal and opetopic sets

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory

To my shame I have to admit that I have as yet not looked much into [opetopes](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/opetope) and opetopic sets.

I am in the process of writing nLab entries on [dendroidal sets](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/dendroidal+set) and noticed that some remarks on the relation to opetopic sets should probably be in order.

Now, I  know that I should just sit down and read the opetopic literature. But while I am busy doing that, and since the [model structure on dendroidal sets](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/model+structure+on+dendroidal+sets) wasn't around when most of it was written: does anyone know more about the relation?

Answer (score 4):

Urs, do you have a reason to think that there'll be much to say about this?  I can see that opetopic and dendroidal sets are both presheaf categories that arise in higher-dimensional category theory.  I can see that in both cases, the small category on which you're taking presheaves has a graphical or geometric interpretation, and there are some "face maps", and there's something tree-like going on.  But beyond that, I don't see what there is to say.  Do you have something in mind?

I just looked in Ittay Weiss's thesis, *Dendroidal Sets*.  "Opetope" is not in the index, nor is the relevant Baez--Dolan paper (Higher Dimensional Algebra III) cited.  So I guess he had no thoughts on the matter.

Comment: I tried to figure out whether opetopic objects are equivalent to dendroidal objects, or if maybe one is a special case of the other.  I gave up just because I did not (yet) find a concise, explicit description of the opetopic base category.


Comment: Yes, defining the category of opetopes (the presheaves on which are the opetopic sets) is no easy task.  Defining the objects seems appreciably easier; it's the maps that make it hard.  

Comment: Tom, no, this was just a naive question. You might read it in part as asking "Can anyone give me a better idea of what opetopic sets are like?" I was hoping that the answer would have been that opetopic sets are somehow a vast generalization of dendroidal sets. That would have given me motivation to look into them more closely. But if you say there is no non-superficial relation, I'll take your word for it. Thanks.

Comment: Greg, thanks for this comment. Even though a negative "result",  that's useful to know. 

Comment: Well, I don't say there is no non-superficial relation - just that after a few minutes' thought, I can't see one.  That doesn't mean much!  